# mysql multiple tables query command to php array - getting error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Below is my SQL Query which i am able to run successfully in PhpMyAdmin .
            [ data from multiple tables similar to IMDB database ]

```
SELECT 
`data`.`code`,
`data`.`movie`,
`movies`.`id`,
`movies`.`name`,
`data`.`person`,
`persons`.`name`,
`persons`.`code`,
`data`.`mode`,
`modes`.`name`
FROM
`data`
INNER JOIN `movies` ON (`data`.`movie` = `movies`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `persons` ON (`data`.`code` = `persons`.`code`)
INNER JOIN `modes` ON (`data`.`mode` = `modes`.`code`)
where `data`.`movie`=1
```

Below is PHP CODE generated by PhpMyAdmin (create PHP Code button) from above command but not fetching any results when used in PHP page (webpage) ,

```
$sql = "SELECT \n"
. " `data`.`code`,\n"
. " `data`.`movie`,\n"
. " `movies`.`id`,\n"
. " `movies`.`name`,\n"
. " `data`.`person`,\n"
. " `persons`.`name`,\n"
. " `persons`.`code`,\n"
. " `data`.`mode`,\n"
. " `modes`.`name`\n"
. "FROM\n"
. " `data`\n"
. " INNER JOIN `movies` ON (`data`.`movie` = `movies`.`id`)\n"
. " INNER JOIN `persons` ON (`data`.`code` = `persons`.`code`)\n"
. " INNER JOIN `modes` ON (`data`.`mode` = `modes`.`code`)\n"
. "where `data`.`movie`=1 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Comment: Please review the FAQ and revise to be a question as well as explain what you have tried and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you need the `\n`s in there?

Comment: Remove all the " . ".  Just wrap the entire SELECT statement in one set of quotes.

Comment: @bansi - print_r($movies); --> below text is displayed in php page
SELECT `data`.`code`, `data`.`movie`, `movies`.`id`, `movies`.`name`, `data`.`person`, `persons`.`name`, `persons`.`code`, `data`.`mode`, `modes`.`name` FROM `data` INNER JOIN `movies` ON (`data`.`movie` = `movies`.`id`) INNER JOIN `persons` ON (`data`.`code` = `persons`.`code`) INNER JOIN `modes` ON (`data`.`mode` = `modes`.`code`) where `data`.`movie`=1 LIMIT 0, 30

Comment: @andrewsi  --> \n s - are generated by PhpMyAdmin ( create PHP code from Mysql Command ) -- i dont require them .

Comment: @ Christopher Ickes --> can you please post the php code here ..?? removing "." ..??  i don't get it.

Comment: @user2755267 - have you checked to see if your statement is being run successfully? What error message is the database returning?

Comment: are you even executing the query? can you post the entire code of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT 
`data`.`code`,
`data`.`movie`,
`movies`.`id`,
`movies`.`name`,
`data`.`person`,
`persons`.`name`,
`persons`.`code`,
`data`.`mode`,
`modes`.`name`
FROM
`data`
INNER JOIN `movies` ON (`data`.`movie` = `movies`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `persons` ON (`data`.`code` = `persons`.`code`)
INNER JOIN `modes` ON (`data`.`mode` = `modes`.`code`)
where `data`.`movie`=1";
```

The \n and . from your question are not required.